# Word found unreadable content in... Downloading file from SSRS in word format from C# app

Tags: c#, azure, reporting-services

I have a C# .net core web app published to Azure and I'm having trouble downloading a report from SSRS (URL based report - hit the URL, SSRS generates the report, app downloads it to memory and serves it to the user for download).  It's a multi-layer application with multiple different people managing these different layers.  Also, nobody else has ever used SSRS in this way, all our previous SSRS reports have been scheduled reports, so none of us know exactly how this works.  But it does, "It works on my machine."

**These are the pieces:**

- Web app deployed on Azure
- Azure SQL Database
- SSRS is running on-prem

I don't control any of these, just the code.  If I open the report on the SSRS site, it pulls the data in from the database just fine.  If I run the app from my computer, it goes out to SSRS and runs the report, which pulls the data from the database and generates the report and feeds it back to me no problem.  After publishing to Azure, I no longer get a valid file back (unreadable content, file is only 3KB when it should be about 20KB).  But I *do* get a file back, so I assume that means SSRS permissions are fine.  And since SSRS can access the database and generate the report if I run it directly in the SSRS interface, I assume the connection to the database from SSRS is fine.  We don't know which layer to look into to troubleshoot this.

**Here are a few things I've tried to see if I could reproduce when I'm running on my machine and their results:**

- Remove access to SSRS for my account - no file is downloaded and I get a 500 error
- Changed database creds to be incorrect - no file is downloaded and I get a 500 error
- Removed WebClient.Credentials = DefaultCredentials from the C# app - no file is downloaded and I get a 500 error

I can't reproduce downloading the report with "unreadable content" when running on my machine.  I don't know who to tell they need to look into something deeper.  At this point, everyone tells me that "It *should* work."  I've included my method that handles the report download to see if there's anything there that can be changed.

```
public FileStreamResult GetReport(string reportAddress)
{
    var net = new WebClient();
    net.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;  //I feel like this could be related, as it's likely different when running on Azure but SSRS still gives me a file instead of a 500 error like when we removed SSRS access for my account to test while running on my machine
    var data = net.DownloadData(reportAddress);
    var content = new MemoryStream(data);
    var contentType = "APPLICATION/octet-stream";
    return new FileStreamResult(content, contentType);
}
```

Any idea on where to look?

**Method execution:**

```
return GetReport("http://server/ReportServer/?/ReportsRoot/ProjectFolder/ReportName&Param1=P1Value&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=wordopenxml");
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in remarks from documentation of [CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.credentialcache.defaultcredentials?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

*The DefaultCredentials property applies only to NTLM, negotiate, and Kerberos-based authentication.*

*DefaultCredentials represents the system credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application. For ASP.NET applications, the default credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated.*

When running on your machine, that I assume is in the same domain of SSRS, `DefaultCredentials` are passing your domain user authentication, because the app is running under your authentication/authorization context, and your code is passing that authentication information in the request, making everything work.

When running on Azure, obviously the code has a local user, not your domain user, breaking the auth chain.

I'd suggest you to investigate ways to use your domain user (or even better an ad hoc user for your app) to create non-default credentials and pass them to the request, it should work.
Maybe investigate the possibility to federate your AD Domain with your Azure subscription (not an expert, but should be possible to join Azure AD whit on premise one).

Comment: That's what I assumed as well.  That's why I tested removing access for my AD account on SSRS to see if I would get an unreadable content error when run locally, but instead I just got an ISE and no file.  Without knowing for sure, I was thinking that meant that whatever Azure is running the application under has access, since it does actually receive a file which was better than what I was getting when I ensured I didn't have access in my test.  Also FWIW, I am using SSO with Azure AD to authenticate on the web app.

Comment: 1/2 Uhm... No credentials and wrong credentials are two very different things, though, and can be responded differently from SSRS. Did you try to open the file that is downloaded from your Azure application with a normal text editor, like Notepad++? If it is really a .docx file the first two characters should be PK, followed by some other stuff (since all office 2003+ documents are zipped xml, basically). My guess is that SSRS is sending some other things like HTML... headers from the request

Comment: 2/2 I also suggest you to add logs to your code and to log the username you are passing in credentials full response headers. You could also write what you're receiveing directly to HttpContext.Response, including the headers... this should help you to debug more specifically, I think...

Comment: The first characters are PK and it does say later in the data word/document.xml.  I did an additional test of just removing the report from SSRS entirely.  On my dev machine, I get a 500 ISE as expected.  But, interestingly, the Azure deployed app still comes back with a word file with unreadable content, even though the report isn't there.  I'm waiting for them to publish my new version with some additional logging to help with debugging.

Comment: *"But, interestingly, the Azure deployed app still comes back with a word file with unreadable content"* You are right, this is really strange... I'm intrigued, can't wait to see what comes from the logs! :)